# How can I change my code so that the value in the output only shows once instead of more than one time using random numbers?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to find the data that is the same in the 2 panda series I show below and put them in the list, but some of the outputs in the lists show up more than once. How can I change my code so the output only shows once?
This is my code for the 2 panda series:

```
N= 10
data1 = []
for i in range(N):
  data1.append(random.randint(1,10))
s1 = pd.Series(data1)
print('Panda Series 1:')
print(s1)
print()

# Creating the second panda series, s2
data2 = []
for i in range(N):
  data2.append(random.randint(5,10))
s2 = pd.Series(data2)
print('Panda Series 2:')
print(s2)
```

This is my code for the data that are the same in the 2 pandas series:

```
same = []
for i in s1.values:
    if i in s2.values:
      same.append(i)
print(same)
```

How can I change it so it only shows the outputs once? For example, this is my output from one of the times that I ran the code:

```
[9, 6, 9, 7, 8]
```

How can I change it so the 9 only shows once? Thank you!

Comment: `result = set(result)`

Comment: @Kraigolas like this? `match = []
for i in s1.values:
    if i in s2.values:
      match.append(i)
match = set(match)
print(match)`

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you don't want any duplicates to appear in your list. You can change it to a set. It would remove the duplicates. Then you can convert to list once again. An important thing to note, once you change it a set, the order will be changed.

```
as_list = [9, 6, 9, 7, 8]
as_set = set(as_list) # This would remove duplicates
as_list = list(as_set) # This would give a list without any duplicates
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you do not care about the order of the same values, you can add them to a set instead of a list. In a set all values are unique by definition.

```
same = set()
for i in s1.values:
    if i in s2.values:
      same.add(i)
print(same)
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your issue would be to make sure that the list **same** is appended only if the value is unique and not already in the list. This can be done using a simple if loop although there are more efficient ways to do it. The following code solves your issue using the if loop:

```
same = []
for i in s1.values:
    if i in s2.values:
      if i not in same:
         same.append(i)
print(same)
```